# Where to write my application's log in OS X?

Tags: macos, logging

I have node-webkit app running in OS X but it doesn't have rights to write to `/var/log` nor to `/private/var/log`. Where should it write to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical place for writing application logs for a user would be:

```
~/Library/Logs/AppName.log
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
/Users/Username/Library/Logs/AppName.log
```

You could also write logs to a defined directory such as:

```
~/Library/Logs/AppNameFolder/AppName.log
```

Logfiles stored in the users `Logs` then can easily be viewed in `Console.app`.